# C++11: is_member_pointer not working for many STL container functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to use is_member_pointer from the type_traits header, with the following syntax, for example:

```
cout << is_member_pointer<decltype(&vector<int>::member)>::value;
```

In the case of vectors, I get a "template argument invalid" and a wordy "type of ... is unknown" message for all iterator functions and all modifier functions except for clear. There are similar faults for other container functions. I have mingw g++ 4.6.2.

Is there a way to help this?

Comment: This might have something to do with the fact that the iterator functions are overloaded: there are two `begin()` and `end()` functions, one for each level of `const`ness.  Similarly, many other functions like `operator[]` and `at` are `const`-overloaded.  On the other hand, `size()` is not `const`-overloaded.

Comment: Can you post a concrete example, the error code and what compiler/version you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem probably is that you [checked the type of overloaded methods](http://ideone.com/wD9fq). That is not possible, since expressions like `&std::vector<int>::begin` have no type (there are two overloads). It is only after casting to the desired type, that it becomes a member function pointer. The cast would look like this:

```
std::cout << std::is_member_pointer<decltype((std::vector<int>::iterator(std::vector<int>::*)())&std::vector<int>::begin)>::value;
```

not very aesthetically pleasing.

With non-overloaded methods, it works.

```
std::cout << std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&std::vector<int>::reserve)>::value;
```

BTW with gcc-4.7, you even get a clearer error message:

```
test.cpp:6:70: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

Comment: Can you fix this, perhaps, by adding a cast that indicates which of the functions you want?

Comment: @templatetypedef: See edit. I thought it would be sort of pointless to cast to proper type in a `decltype` - you could just write the type directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this appears to be an adequate solution for me.

Comment: Or maybe not; I'd like to use "is_member_pointer" with "enable_if" as template argument, and it seems I can't cast type that way...

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Why? Maybe you just need `typename`. If you just need to check `.begin` exists, you can check for `decltype<declval<Vector>().begin()>`.

Comment: Um, thanks for that again... I've been learning C++ for about a month and template metaprogramming appears to be rather inscrutable at times.